# R to Javascript

Tags: javascript, r

I am trying to convert this R code to Javascript

The code is taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/line-intersection-with-circle-on-a-sphere-globe-or-earth

Here is the code:

```
# Constants
degree <- 2 * pi / 360
radian = 1 / degree
radius <- 6371007.2 # meters

# Input
a0 <- c(48.139115, 11.578081) * degree # Point A in (lat, lon)
b0 <- c(48.146303, 11.593102) * degree # Point B
c0 <- c(48.137024, 11.575249) * degree # Center
r <- 1000.0                            # Radius (meters)

# Projection
A <- a0 * c(1, cos(c0[1])) * radius
B <- b0 * c(1, cos(c0[1])) * radius
C <- c0 * c(1, cos(c0[1])) * radius

# Compute coefficients of the quadratic equation
v <- A - C; u <- B - A
alpha <- sum(u * u)
beta <- sum(u * v)
gamma <- sum(v * v) - r^2

# Solve the equation.
`%pm%` <- function(x,y) c(x+y, x-y)
t <- (-beta %pm% sqrt(beta^2 - alpha * gamma)) / alpha
t <- t[0 <= t & t <= 1]             # Limit the solution to arc a0-b0.
x <- (a0 + (b0-a0) %o% t) * radian  # Columns are (lat, lon)
```

Here is my attempt:

```
console.log('Hello world!')
const degree = 2 * Math.PI / 360
const radian = 1 / degree
const radius = 6371007.2 // meters

// Input
const a0 = [48.139115, 11.578081].map((e)=>e*degree) // Point A
console.log(a0)
const b0 = [48.146303, 11.593102].map((e)=>e*degree) // Point B
const c0 = [48.137024, 11.575249].map((e)=>e*degree) // Center
const r = 1000 // Radius (meters)

// Projection

const factor = [1, Math.cos(c0[1])].map(e=>e*radius)
const A = a0.map((e,i)=>e * factor[i])
const B = b0.map((e,i)=>e * factor[i])
const C = c0.map((e,i)=>e * factor[i])


// Compute coefficients of the quadratic equation
const v = A.map((e,i)=>e- C[i])
const u = B.map((e,i)=>e- A[i])

const alpha = u.reduce((p,a,i)=> p+a* u[i],0)
const beta = u.reduce((p,a,i)=> p+a* v[i],0)
const gamma = v.reduce((p,a,i)=> p+a* v[i],0) - r^2

/**
// Solve the equation.
    `%pm%` <- function(x,y) c(x+y, x-y)
t <- (-beta %pm% sqrt(beta^2 - alpha * gamma)) / alpha
t <- t[0 <= t & t <= 1]             # Limit the solution to arc a0-b0.
    x <- (a0 + (b0-a0) %o% t) * radian  # Columns are (lat, lon)
print(x)

 */
```

I am stuck at the last part here :

```
// Solve the equation.
    `%pm%` <- function(x,y) c(x+y, x-y)
t <- (-beta %pm% sqrt(beta^2 - alpha * gamma)) / alpha
t <- t[0 <= t & t <= 1]             # Limit the solution to arc a0-b0.
    x <- (a0 + (b0-a0) %o% t) * radian  # Columns are (lat, lon)
print(x)
```

What does `%pm%` and t[0 <= t & t <= 1]   and  %o%  mean ?

Comment: Your last four lines are doing a few somewhat non trivial things, but the code is _vectorized_ (while JS is not), so there might not be any easy to convert the code.

Answer (score 0):

`%pm%` is defined in your code :  `%pm% <- function(x,y) c(x+y, x-y)`.
Since it appears that `t` is a vector (js array) this part

```
t[0 <= t & t <= 1]
```

redefines it as numbers between 0 and 1 (notice that there are no commas, hence only one dimension).

And last but not least is `%o%` which is short for the [`outer`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/outer) function.